# Magento eCommerce Templates

Tags: templates, magento, e-commerce

I am trying to port a site design from OSCommerce to Magento and I am finding it quite difficult. The documentation is quite poor tbh. Has anyone done this or used Magento in anyway? Any good tutorials/guides out there, if not for porting then just for building a template from scratch?

Any help would be great, I've already been looking at this for a day or so and am getting no where...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The designers guide is a good starting point.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide

Comment: it's not great to be honest, gives a good overview but I want to get my hands dirty. a tutorial on building a template form scratch would be ideal...